# Foursquare API Error 403 - User not authorized to edit venue

Tags: api, oauth, foursquare

We are trying to update details information for serveral Venues in behalf of our clients/users by using Foursquare API.

It works pretty well for most of the clients, and we are using their own personal oauth credentials most of the time.

BTW, we have a lot of problems with some clients/accounts, because we are getting this error when trying to update the venues:

```
{
  "meta": {
    "code": 403,
    "errorType": "not_authorized",
    "errorDetail": "User not authorized to edit venue",
    "requestId": "59bba14e351e3d0e31fcf9f1"
  },
  "notifications": [
    {
        "type": "notificationTray",
        "item": {
            "unreadCount": 0
        }
    }
],
"response": {}
```

We’ve checked the API limits and everything it’s correct. We’ve also checked the account Oauth token several times and it’s correct. Even we are using the 'venues/managed’ endpoint to ensure that the given Oauth credential can manage the given Venue and everything looks fine.

Any idea about what's happening?

Comment: You must be venue manager or superuser to edit a venue.

Comment: I'm a manager... In fact, when requesting the 'venues/managed endpoint with the same OAuth token the Venue appears on the response.